# In php code, use shell_exec correctly in my case

Tags: php, linux

I have question about how to save log in correctly directory. My php code:

```
public static function log(test $testination) {

    echo($testination->getDetails()."\n");
    
     $log_filename = shell_exec("cd; ~/log/");
     $log_filename2 = "log";
 
    if (!file_exists($log_filename2))
    {
        mkdir($log_filename, 0777, true);
    }

    $log_file_data =$log_filename.'/logs_' . date('d-M-Y') . '.log';
    file_put_contents($log_file_data, var_dump($testination) . "\n", FILE_APPEND);

}
```

in this code, I create a folder in the same place as my PHP file, then create folder log if this not exist.

I want to save in begining (just cd) then create log folder if this not exist I try this code

```
 $log_filename = shell_exec("cd; ~/log/");
```

i get warning/error

```
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/logs_18-Aug-2020.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /test/test/Helper.php on line 318
```

Any idea how to do it? Please im stuck.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain more information. What do you mean by "save in begining"? What keeps you from creating the log directory there and use a static, non-computed directory name in your application?

Comment: "I want to save in beginning (just cd)" in linux console in my example ```putty``` if u are in directory like test/test and write  cd u will come in the beginning. My task is change  directory so I CANT KEEP MY LOG FILE IN THE SAME DIRECTORY.

Answer (score -1):

That's not how you should use `file_put_contents`: it does not know anything about that attempt to change the directory, as this will not affect the execution of PHP. If you want to get the directory of the current PHP file, you can use `basename(__DIR__)`

Additionall, `cd; ~/log/` won't work in your shell as well.

Comment: u dont understand me, i want create file in what directory, not get file from that directory

Comment: Can you explain that further? What would happen if you used `file_put_contents(basename(__DIR__) . '/logs', 'test')`? How does this differ from what you want to achieve?

Comment: u mean write something like this?  ```file_put_contents(basename( ~/log/). $log_file_data, var_dump($testination) . "\n", FILE_APPEND); ```

Comment: No, use `basename(__DIR__)`  if the file should be placed in the same directory than the script itself. The `~`  is some bash thing and won't work in PHP

Comment: in my case it place in the same direction. lol. I need change direction. I dont need save in the same direction. i need save in ```~/log/ ```direction. im now in  ```/test/test/``` direction to get in the i need write ```cd  ~/log/ ``` or ```cd ```and then ```cd  ~/log/```.

Comment: `cd`  won't help you there. What keeps you from simply writing the proper path there?

Comment: how to go back without ```cd``` in the beginning?

Comment: What do you mean by "go back"? Have you tried looking up what `basename` does?

Comment: i try look in google example ```basename``` i dont found any example who work in my case. U understand  linux server? ```cd``` command turn back in the beginning in what place exist ```log``` folder, in what folder i want put new generated file. if folder dont exist create it. Now putting file in same place like script.

Comment: Yes, I know what a linux server is. Working on them nearly every day since years. But I don't get what you mean by "turn back in the beginning". Also, if you tried to use `basename`, please edit your question to contain all attempts

Comment: i dont try use ```basename``` because i cant found how to use it correctly for example. In linux server from zero address  i have folder ```"log"``` my php script in ```/test/test```.  I need save in ```"log"``` folder from the zero. if dont exist create folder (you can see my if statement) Write please ```basename``` example for my case please.

Comment: What do you mean by "the zero"? Are you simply looking for `/var` - that does not need any switching of directories

Comment: my task is switch directory if i can save in the same directory i dont need any help lol. Zero directory i call what directory then u are in like example test/test and use ```cd``` and get back from beginning (like in putty)

Comment: Please edit your question to contain all such information. Also, share your attempts there